# print \r statement doesn't update on the same line

Tags: perl

I use Activestate Perl at work (dont hate me).

I used to have this little sub that I've used to use all the time. It's a countdown sleep, and would show the countdown on the screen during execution on the same line, and not in new lines.

Here,

```
sub countdownsleep {
    my $prefix = shift;
    my $x = shift;
    my $t = 1 *$x;
    my ($m,$s);
     my $stoptime = time + $t;
     while((my $now = time) < $stoptime) {
       printf( "$prefix %02d:%02d\r", ($stoptime - $now) / 60, ($stoptime - $now) % 60);
       $m = ($stoptime - $now) / 60;
       $s = ($stoptime - $now) % 60;
       select(undef,undef,undef,1);
     }
}

countdownsleep("Sleep... ",5);
```

The output would look like :

```
Sleep... <5..0>  # on the same line on the same spot.
```

It used to work on previous perl versions... does anyone know why this is so? and if there's a way to fix it perhaps?

Comment: What version did it work on, what version is it not working on?

Comment: So I guess it is showing up on multiple lines now.  Has the command prompt and Windows version stayed the same?

Comment: Please add the output of `perl -v` and `chcp`, and let me know when you do by writing a comment with `@ikegami` in it.

Comment: Sorry for replying late.
Active code page: 437

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

To clarify my question further,.. I am not saying that I am not seeing any output, I am saying \r is acting as \n

Answer (score 4):

On most systems, [`STDOUT` is line buffered](http://www.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) meaning `print` and `printf` will only display after a `\n` is printed. So if you're trying to do this countdown on `STDOUT` it will print nothing until the program ends.

You can temporarily turn this off on the currently selected filehandle with [`local $| = 1`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles).

```
while((my $now = time) < $stoptime) {
    local $| = 1;
    printf( "$prefix %02d:%02d\r", ($stoptime - $now) / 60, ($stoptime - $now) % 60);
    sleep 1;
}
```

Side note: `select(undef,undef,undef,1);` is an obfuscated way of writing `sleep 1`.

Comment: He's not saying he's not seeing any output, he's saying `\r` is acting as `\n` (or maybe a vertical tab???). `$|=1` isn't going to change that.

Comment: @ikegami It's not 100% clear what output the OP is seeing, but on Unix their code has this problem for sure.

Comment: @ Schwer n: What I was seeing is an output where I constantly see the "sleep...5" in new lines. Like this :

Sleep...5

Sleep...4

Sleep...3

Sleep...2

Sleep...1

Sleep...0